# Installing Kali Linux in Docker and accessing it's GUI over the browser

Tags: linux, docker, kali-linux, nginx

so I'm pretty new to docker and all that stuff.
I would like to install Kali Linux as a Docker container and access it's GUI from the browser. How do I do that? I use Portainer as a GUI for managing the docker containers.

If possible, I'd like to have access to the kali GUI over a domain.
I'm already using nginx proxy manager in a docker container on my machine.
I also installed a desktop environment on the container but I have no idea how to access it.

Thanks for your help in advance

PS: I'm sorry if this question is stupid or so, as I said I'm a newbie working with docker and all that, so forgive me

Answer (score 0):

Dear Kindly use below dockerfile to deploy kali docker container and for accessing it from web, Kindly [click here](https://superuser.com/questions/1721163/installing-kali-linux-in-docker-and-accessing-its-gui-over-the-browser)

```
#Purpose: Installing Kali GUI in docker
From kalilinux/kali-rolling
#RUN apt-get install apt-utils -y
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt install tzdata -y && apt install net-tools vim man file -y
RUN apt-get install kali-linux-headless -y
RUN  apt-get install -y vim perl wget tar man sudo adduser netstat-nat net-tools curl w3m
RUN useradd -m  -s /bin/bash kali
RUN usermod -aG sudo kali && echo "kali ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/kali
RUN chmod 044 /etc/sudoers.d/kali
USER kali:kali
WORKDIR /home/kali
#browser implementation
RUN apt-get install openssl shellinabox -y
#RUN echo -e "# TCP port that shellinboxd's webserver listens on\nSHELLINABOX_PORT=443\n#specify the IP address of a destination SSH server\nSHELLINABOX_ARGS=\"--o-beep -s /:SSH:192.168.1.7\"\n# if you want to restrict access to shellinaboxd from localhost only\nSHELLINABOX_ARGS=\"--o-beep -s /:SSH:192.168.1.7 --localhost-only"\" >> /etc/default/shellinabox
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
#docker run -itd --privileged #type_here_target_image_id /usr/sbin/init #command to run systemctl inside docker container
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).